# Is there a way to use Loopnum instead of threadNum in the Jmeter variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

I am setting my Jmeter variable using this:

```
${__setProperty(id_${__threadNum},${id},)}
```

And using this in another request like this:

```
${__P(id_${__threadNum},)}
```

However I want to run the loop instead of the thread. How can i change it to so it is loopNum instead of the thread

Can i use this below when i want to use the loop instead of the thread

I am setting my Jmeter variable using this:

```
${__setProperty(id_${__iterationNum},${id},)}
```

And using this in another request like this:

```
${__P(id_${__iterationNum},)}
```

This is how i want to run it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And where do you set this `${__iterationNum}` variable? It's not a normal [JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

And if you have in mind [__iterationNum() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup) which is a part of JMeter Plugins - you first need to install the **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) and change your syntax to `${__iterationNum}`

If you don't want or cannot use the plugins since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you can access the current iteration of the Thread Group as:

`${__jm__Thread Group__idx}`

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work same as __threadNum I am using the loop count 10 instead of the thread group 10.

Comment: The above approach returns the current Thread Group iteration number, if you want to get the number of loops you need to use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) like: `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getSamplerController().getProperty('LoopController.loops'),)}`

Comment: but how would use the property in the next request? same as this? ${__P(id_${__threadNum},)}

Comment: the problem I am trying to solve is to have (id) saved as global variable from the response of the first request and use it in another request